# Dynamics AX crashes via RDP on Microsoft Surface Pro devices

Tags: azure, axapta, rdp, surface

We are testing the use of Dynamics AX on a remote server in Azure.

So we start an RDP session, start AX and it works just fine.
However, when doing the same from a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 and Pro 4 device, the app crashes as soon as it's opened.

It works on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 on any other device. Works fine on a VM. 
It doesn't work on any Surface Pro device, no matter what OS is installed on it.

When I RDP on one device, start the app and then take over that session on a Surface Pro the app crashes as soon as the session is open.

Tried with Remote Desktop Manager as well as RD Tabs -> Same issue
Tried changing some DPI settings but still same problem.
Tried the suggested fix with the external manifest file (see [here](https://blog.brankovucinec.com/2016/03/19/fix-remote-desktop-dpi-scaling-issues/)), but this didn't work either.

I never seen this behaviour before.
Any suggestions?

What is so special on a Microsoft Surface compared to any other device out there.

Event Viewer just logs an APPCRASH event:

> Problem signature:
>
> Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>
> Application Name: Ax32.exe
>
> Application Version:  6.3.2000.326
>
> Application Timestamp:    55723de2
>
> Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Fault Module Version: 6.3.9600.18666
>
> Fault Module Timestamp:   58f32841
>
> Exception Code:   e0434352
>
> Exception Offset: 00015608
>
> OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.144.8
>
> Locale ID:    2067
>
> Additional Information 1: efb4
>
> Additional Information 2: efb4bfa9723187835735c8e19d0ec036
>
> Additional Information 3: 5979
>
> Additional Information 4: 5979496dad26b2cc5fdeb2f966f15373

Comment: Just for a try: We had strange issues (freezing of AOT etc.) with fingerprint scanners in our HP notebooks and after uninstalling the according drivers the issue was 'solved'. Therefore you may want to try disabling the fingerprint scanner of your surface - see [here](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/39966/71761) for a community thread about it.

Comment: I can start and use AX 2012 R3 in an RDP session on my Surface pro 4. The AX is not hosted in Azure, though, but in a customer infrastructure. What is your AX version?

Comment: @DAXaholic
There is no fingerprint scanner on a MS Surface device. Not sure what other devices I could disable.
I'll try to start it in Clean Boot and enable one by one.

Comment: @FH-Inway
It's AX 2012 R3 as well here. However, the server is in Azure (Server 2012 R2)

Comment: @ATur Not on the device itself but on the Type Cover 4 which is compatible with the Pro 3 - anyway if you don't have one then ignore it :)

Comment: You're running the R3 CU9 kernel. You might want to test installing a more recent kernel version and hope Microsoft has fixed this. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2012/03/29/overview-of-microsoft-dynamics-ax-build-numbers/